# 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first, console-application

I am trying to to a simple linq query on a database but i'm getting this error:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{

    public static PetersContext db = new PetersContext();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var sizeList = from ProductSizes in db.Sizes
                       where ProductSizes.SizeScale.Equals(1)
                       select (ProductSizes.SizeDesc);


        foreach (var size in sizeList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(size);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The sizes table has a row called SizeScaleId which is a foreign key to the SizeScale table,

Each Size has a SizeScaleID

What i want to return is a list of sizes with a SizeScaleID of (1)
and that should be "S","M","L","XL","XXL","3XL","4XL"

I have tried a few things but cant get passed this error

Comment: so... `where ProductSizes.SizeScale.Id == 1` ? or possibly `where ProductSizes.SizeScaleId == 1` ?

Comment: Yep, :D, thought i tried that,

Comment: was ProductSizes.SizeScale == 1

Comment: So did you solve the issue with using  `where ProductSizes.SizeScale.SizeScaleID == 1`?